# ¿problema en la función de un botón java?

Tags: java

tengo un problema cuando se ejecuta la acción de un botón, la cosa es que al presionar el botón este primero por medio de un if me suma 1+ a un contador, después de hacer esto envía el numero a un textfield y después una acción de UPDATE me actualiza ese numero que esta en el textfield a la BD. el problema es que presiono el botón y en el textfiel me aparece 1 y en la bd sigue en 0, vuelvo a presionar el botón y en el textfield me aparece en 2 y en la bd en 1 y así sucesivamente, es como si no cogiera la primera vez que presiono el botón.

el evento del botón es este

```
private void btnGuardarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

    conexion objConexion = new conexion();
     personasBL oPersonas = recuperarDatosGui();
    
     
    
    if (rbInscrito.isSelected()) {
        
        FormulariosVendidosTotal++;


     }else if(rbMatriculado.isSelected()) {
        FormulariosVendidosTotal++;
         }

                         //MANDA EL NUMERO DEL CONTADOR A UN TXT 
        txtFormVTotal.setText(String.valueOf(FormulariosVendidosTotal));
        
            //ACTUALIZA EL NUMERO EN LA BD, RECOGIENDO EL NUMERO DEL TXT QUE TIENE EL CONTADOR
     String strSentenciaInser = String.format("UPDATE contador SET formVendiTotal='%s'",oPersonas.getFormVTotal());
     objConexion.ejecutarSentenciaSQL(strSentenciaInser); 
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

no se como funciona pero así me sirvió, agrdezco si alguin me dice porque fue el inconveniente

```
private void btnGuardarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

conexion objConexion = new conexion();
 personasBL oPersonas = recuperarDatosGui();

 

if (rbInscrito.isSelected()) {
    
    FormulariosVendidosTotal++;


 }else if(rbMatriculado.isSelected()) {
    FormulariosVendidosTotal++;
     }

                     //MANDA EL NUMERO DEL CONTADOR A UN TXT 
    txtFormVTotal.setText(String.valueOf(FormulariosVendidosTotal));
    actu();   
} 



    public void actu(){
      conexion objConexion = new conexion();
     personasBL oPersonas = recuperarDatosGui();

        
        
            //ACTUALIZA EL NUMERO EN LA BD, RECOGIENDO EL NUMERO DEL TXT QUE TIENE EL CONTADOR
     String strSentenciaInser = String.format("UPDATE contador SET formVendiTotal='%s'",oPersonas.getFormVTotal());
     objConexion.ejecutarSentenciaSQL(strSentenciaInser); 

};
```

Comment: No entiendo bien tu código pero claramente la diferencia está en el if else ahí la diferencia, has pruebas con ello.

Comment: listo, gracias pues lo realice como el código de arriba y me funciono